# Why Fb:like does not display the send button on IE8 while using XFBML?

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-8, facebook-like

I'm trying to display the like + send button on a test page. The code i'm using to display the button is:

```
<fb:like href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like" send="true" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

You can see that i have specified "layout=button_count" and "send=true" parameters. However only the like button is showed on IE8 (other browsers works fine) and not with the "button_count" layout but with the "standard" layout.

Do you have any clue?

Here is the full html+sdk+fbml code you can paste in your testpage:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="Just a test page" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<fb:like href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like" send="true" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it's a Facebook bug.
I've posted it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/216063688545697.